# How do I pass nested context to a Django template? Eg All posts from all users with current_user_likes_post (True or False) for each post

Tags: django

So if user A likes posts 1 and 2, and user B likes post 3, my output at /posts/ when user = A would be something like:

- Post 1 - Like
- Post 2 - Like
- Post 3 - You like this - Unlike
- Post 4 - You like this - Unlike

I know how to pass all posts using the following, but how can I pass a boolean `user_likes_this_post variable` for each post?

```
def posts_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    ...
    return (render, request, posts.html, {'posts':posts })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# views.py
User_likes_ids = UserLikes.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('post_id', flat=True)
posts = Post.objects.all()

# template.html
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.id in user_likes_ids %}you like this - unlike{% else %}like{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```